Confused with predicate in のが (cleft?) sentence?
Dungeon Meshi episode 18, チルチャック laments over how despite the fact that their party had such difficulty heading to the surface of the dungeon they were traversing, when they realize they need to go back down deeper, they are met with a dark ominous staircase with blood on it:

上の階への階段はあれほど見つからなかったのが➡
進むと決めた途端これだ。
Finding away back up was rough,
so of course, when we try to go back down,
we run into something like
this. [shows translation]

のが does not seem to be a shortening of のだが even though that makes more sense to me (it would certainly be translated as so if it was).
I have a really hard time interpreting this sentence. It doesn't seem like a cleft sentence because the の has no reason as I see it to correspond to これだ. It doesn't make much sense to me as a nominalizer either (that also doesn't correspond to これ as a predicate).
I guess one could see this as two clauses in a kinda messy sentence, but I kinda doubt that too because I would expect that to be in something more free-flow like a podcast, not a line of dialogue said straightly.
How should one break down this sentence?
